# Single-Sign-On with TYPO3 as authentication source

Tags: typo3, single-sign-on

I have a TYPO3-Installation and a Web-application, both located on different servers; TYPO3 is reachable via "domain.com", the web-application via "subdomain.domain.com".

The task: Logged-in frontend-users (fe_users) of TYPO3 shall be able to access the web-application without having to authenticate again.

(This is sort of a single-sign-on, where TYPO3 is the leading authentication provider. I find lots of examples where LDAP or other systems are the leading one, but none with TYPO3 being the authentication source.)

How would one implement this? Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by setting up TYPO3 as OAuth2 provider using one of the following 2 extensions:

- [OAuth2 Server for TYPO3](https://github.com/fgtclb/typo3-oauth2-server)
- [OAuth2 Server](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/oauth2_server)

Both describe how to set them up in their README.

Afterwards you can register TYPO3 as OAuth2 provider/server in your web application. Your web application then needs to implement an OAuth2 client workflow. How this should happen exactly depends on your web application but is very likely beyond the scope of this question.